# Python3.4 **kwargs, unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, function, dictionary, keyword-argument

I have a dictionary of functions, all of which use 1 or 2 optional arguments. I want to iterate through this dictionary and pass both arguments to each iterated function, and have the functions that only need 1 argument to ignore the second. In these cases, however, I get an unexpected keyword argument error.

```
def getNumFrames(self, **kwargs):
    return len(self.x)

def getConcentration(self, **kwargs):
    if ((not gradient) or (not maxX)):
        return 0
    return (gradient / maxX) * self.x[0]

fields = {'numFrames': getNumFrames, 'concentration': getConcentration}


for field, fieldFunction in fields.items():
        for track in tracks:
             fieldFunction(object, maxX = 10, gradient = 2)
```

In this example, getConcentration would work, but getFrames would say maxX is an unexpected keyword.

*I edited my post to include my actual minimalist code, as was suggested.

Comment: Please post your *actual* minimal example code that demonstrates the problem. This code has a syntax error (missing colon in definition of func2). Also, you can't just use arbitrary  arguments in your function - you need to get them from the `kwargs` dictionary. Finally, it is bad practice to shadow a built-in name, like `object`.

Comment: Would keeping the second parameter optional having a default value `None` not work?

Answer (score 3):

A much better way to avoid all of this trouble is to use the following paradigm:

```
def func(obj, **kwargs):
    return obj + kwargs.get(a, 0) + kwargs.get(b,0)
```

This makes use of the fact that `kwargs` is a dictionary consisting of the passed arguments and their values and `get()` performs lookup and returns a default value if the key does not exist.

*Always* access your named arguments through the dictionary `kwargs`. This makes your life much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

I would go about this by creating a function like the one below with the second parameter optional.

```
func (obj, a = 0, b = 0):
    return obj + a + b
```